# How to deal with user defined files in `Makefile.am`

Tags: autotools

I used to write makefiles from scratch, relying on GNU extensions, and now that I am trying to move on to autotools, I get stuck with something: in the code that I am working on, users usually contribute and write some code of their own they can put in a defined directory (potentially substituing existing files).

In a written-by-hand Makefile, I could deal with that (i.e. not knowing what a user would want to do) with a load of `wildcard`, `dir` and `notdir` (because directories could be nested). If a user could define their own problem, defined in a sole variable named `PROBLEM` that would be located in `src/` where sources would be, I would come up with something like:

```
# Define all global objects
SRCDIR = src
SRCFILES = $(wildcard $(SRCDIR)/*f90)
SRCOBJ = $(notdir $(SRCFILES:.f90=.o))
# Define user defined objects
PRBDIR = src/$(PROBLEM)
PRBFILES = $(wildcard $(PRBDIR)/*f90)
PRBOBJ = $(notdir $(PRBFILES:.f90=.o))

ALLOBJ = $(PRBOBJ) $(SRCOBJ)

# Generic rule
%.o: %.f90
        $(F90) $(FCFLAGS) -c $< -o $@ 

# Compile main executable
main: $(ALLOBJ)
        $(F90) $(FCFLAGS) -o main $@
```

If I more or less put this piece of code in a `Makefile.am`, it will complain that `wildcard` and `notdir` are `non-POSIX variable name (probably a GNU make extension)` and I'm stuck.
The first solution I came up with was to explicitly define all the source files by hand... which would be fine there was no one else adding their own stuff.
The second solution I got is to define variables in `configure.ac` that will contain the information I am looking for, but it means using shell commands, which I find rather inelegant:

```
AC_SUBST([PRBFILES], [$(ls -p src/$PROBLEM | grep -v /)])
AC_MSG_RESULT([$PRBFILES])

AC_SUBST([PRBSUBDIRS], [$(ls -p src/$PROBLEM | grep /)])
AC_MSG_RESULT([$PRBSUBDIRS])
```

Doing so, I guess I could then use a regular substitution on `$PRBFILES` in `Makefile.am` to retrieve `PRBOBJ` as I did in the previous example.

Is there a better way to do it?

I wanted to move to autotools for sake of genericity (and it is definitely great to deal with external libraries), and now I feel like I'm going backwards on this, but it is probably because I missed something so far.

Comment: Can you explain a little more about the nature of these user-supplied files?  For example, are users just customizing their own builds with these, or are they making contributions that you are integrating into the project?  Do I understand correctly that the files in question are Fortran source files?  And when you say "potentially substituing existing files", do you mean modifying the contents of distributed files, or removing distributed files in favor of other, differently-named files?

Comment: To specify a bit more: it is a research code with the main part of the code that is "static" and at least with an initial conditions source file to define the problem to run that will vary from one user to the other. In addition to that, users sometimes need to modify the physics of the code and historically that was done by duplicating some files and modifying them in a separate folder. You are right guessing that it is a Fortran project. I'm aware that some of the things I described are not ideal from a software development point of view but habits die hard within users.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

### General

You're experiencing friction because your project style blurs the role distinctions that the Autotools are designed around.  The autotools suppose that there are

- **project maintainers**, who are responsible for preparing and distributing autotooled source packages;
- **builders**, who obtain source packages and build and install them on local systems; and
- **users**, who run the installed software.

There can, of course, be overlap among these.  The point here is that anyone contributing source to the project is operating in the role of a maintainer, and maintaining the build system is one of the duties attending that role.  You would like to somehow provide for maintainers (in this sense) to be relieved of build-system maintenance responsibility.  That's an ok objective, but the Autotools don't provide anything aimed specifically at that.

Within the scope of that issue, you are also running up against the Autotools' design philosophy of supporting maximum portability among UNIX-like systems.  One of the results of that philosophy is that the Autotools discourage and perhaps even actively reject makefile code that relies on `make` extensions, including those provided by GNU `make`.

That does not mean that you cannot adopt an Autotools build system, but it does mean that doing so will be more complicated than usual.  I see three main alternatives.

### Alternative 1: facilitate project maintainer activity

In a build system relying on Automake, all source files *should* be designated explicitly in the Automake inputs (`Makefile.am`, *etc*).  Furthermore, if the Automake inputs are modified, then of course Automake and maybe other autotools need to be re-run.  The `autoreconf` program is often sufficient for this, but for projects with more complex requirements, there is a convention of providing a shell script named `autogen.sh`.  **You could provide an `autogen.sh` that scans the sources for user contributions / modifications and updates the appropriate Automake inputs, then runs `autoreconf`.**  This would still leave you writing shell commands, but perhaps you would find it more elegant in the context of an explicit shell script.

This alternative requires builders to have the Autotools installed, and it may be sensitive to which versions of the various tools they have.

### Alternative 2: build-time determination

If you don't want your users to be responsible for rebuilding the build system, and / or you don't want a build-time dependency on the autotools, then you're stuck with identifying the user-varying source files during project configuration.  The approach you offer as "inelegant" in the question is an example of this.  I have no problem at all with writing shell code in `configure.ac` where you need something for which no macro has been provided, but I would probably choose a slightly different implementation:

```
AC_MSG_CHECKING([for problem files])
PRBFILES=$(find "src/$PROBLEM" -maxdepth 1 -type f)
AC_SUBST([PRBFILES])
AC_MSG_RESULT([$PRBFILES])

AC_MSG_CHECKING([for problem subdirectories])
PRBSUBDIRS=$(find "src/$PROBLEM" -mindepth 1 -maxdepth 1 -type d)
AC_SUBST([PRBSUBDIRS])
AC_MSG_RESULT([$PRBSUBDIRS])
```

Do note that, in contrast with your version, that will not put trailing slashes on the directory names in `$PRBSUBDIRS`.

### Alternative 3: project redesign

The code you describe seems not to be structured as a complete project, as the ordinary usage mode involves third parties building it together with their own code to create custom executables.  But that has a lot of similarities with a *library* or a Fortran *module*.  Perhaps it would be to your advantage to better separate the bits you're providing from those that your users are providing, so as to sidestep the issue.  Build your project, without any user contributions, as a library or module.  If you want to provide a similar level of support for users combining that with their own code, then write and distribute a tool for that, perhaps an the form of a script around a GNU makefile such as you are used to providing.

Comment: What I found inelegant in writing shell code was that autotools is supposed to be shell agnostic and I am afraid of writing something that won't be generic enough. Leaving this point aside, your 2nd alternative is indeed better than what I first wrote.

Comment: @MBR, the Autotools in general, and autoconf in particular, are shell-agnostic in the sense that their objective is to create a portable (POSIX) shell script.  That is in no way in conflict with (portable) shell code appearing in `configure.ac`.  In fact, the Autoconf manual contains an entire chapter on writing portable shell code, and portable shell code is ultimately what's at the bottom of the macro stack.

Comment: By the way, I had to add `-printf "%p "` to the `find` command-line to avoid newlines.